# Bash determine if variable name contains a string

Tags: bash, variables

I would like to test if the name of a variable given as argument to a function contains a certain string, and do different actions if it does/does not.

Here is a very basic description of what I want to achieve:

```
#!/bin/bash

 varA="a"
 varB="b"
 varC="c"
 varD="d"
 varE="e"
 varF="f"

 function1 ()
 {
         if name of argument $1 does not contain "A"; then
                echo "no A in $1"
                further actions done using the value of varA and others...
         elif name of argument $1 contains "A"; then
                echo "A in $1"
                further actions done using the value of varA and others...
         fi
 }

 function1 $varA $varB $varC
 function1 $varD $varE $varF
```

And when running this would give

```
A in varA
no A in varD
```

I saw while doing some research that the name of a variable could be referred to as ${!var@}, so here is the code I tried:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3 varA="a"
  4 varB="b"
  5 varC="c"
  6 varD="d"
  7 varE="e"
  8 varF="f"
  9 
 10 function1 ()
 11 {
 12         if [[ "${!1@}" != *"A" ]]; then
 13                 echo "no A in $1"
 14         elif [[ "${!1@}" == *"A" ]]; then
 15                 echo "A in $1"
 16         fi
 17 }
 18 
 19 function1 $varA $varB $varC
 20 function1 $varD $varE $varF
```

But when running the script it gives the following error messages:

```
./testx.sh: line 12: ${!1@}: bad substitution
./testx.sh: line 12: ${!1@}: bad substitution
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's possible with positional arguments.  When the function is called the variables are replaced with values already so there is no variable name to refer to.

Comment: The call is actually `function1 $varA $varB $varC` (see my second code), and I am not using the values of the variables here, but in the real script I am working on, I want to use their values to perform other actions in the function.

Comment: @arielle: OK. In that case, It's not possible. Note that `${!prefix@}`  "Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with `prefix`"; that is, it is the equivalent to the file glob `prefix*`, but over the names of shell variables. `prefix` is just a string of characters.

Comment: I see. Then why can't I use `${!@}`? Shouldn't this expand to the names of all arguments, something like `varA varB varC` or `$varA $varB $varC`? Both would be good for what I want to do. When I try it it gives some empty lines as output.

Comment: @arielle: `{!@}` is not valid, but if it were valid it would be the list of all *variables*. An argument is just a string; arguments don't have names. (More precisely, they do have names: `$1`, `$2`, ...., but those are parameter names, not variable names. The expression which produced the argument is not its name.) The reason you can't do what you want to do is that the argument has already undergone parameter expansion by the time your function sees it, so it is just a string (which is the value of the variable).

Comment: Ok I get that, thank you for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "test if the **name of a variable**" then give that to the function:

```
function1 varA
```

Not the contents of the variable:

```
function1 $varA             # INCORRECT
```

Then, you could test the name of the variable inside the function:

```
if [[ $1 == *A* ]]; then
```

The script could be as this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

function1 ()
{
        if [[ $1 == *A* ]]; then
               echo "A in $1"
        else
               echo "no A in $1"
        fi
}

function1 varA varB varC
function1 varD varE varF
```

IF you need "the value of the var" inside the function, then just use this:

```
value=${!1}
```

That is called "indirect expansion" inside the `man bash`.

After that, `value` will contain a copy of the variable named in `$1`.

To change the value of the variable pointed by `$1`, use this:

```
declare $1=newvalue
```

Or, quite insecure if the value of $1 could be set by an external user:

```
eval $1=newvalue
```

---

The use of `${!var*}` (or `${!var@}`) is to get a *list* of all variables that use a name that start with `var`. Not to reference a particular variable.

```
$ eval var{A..F}=1               # create the list of variables
$ echo ${!var*}                  # use the expansion to list variables
varA varB varC varD varE varF
```

---

The expansion of `${!1*}` should have been the list of variables that start with a `1`. Those variable names are invalid (except as positional parameters) in bash. That is: variable names could not start with a number.

That expansion is (therefore) an error, and reported as so by bash.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you for taking the time to explain this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have been doing

```
function1 "${!var*}"
```

and inside the function

```
if [[ "$1" == *"A"* ]]
then
  echo "At least one variable name  has patttern A"
fi
```

Comment: but in my real script I want to use the value of the first argument to do more actions inside the function, not just its name, would it still work?

Comment: Might not be possible with positional arguments @arielle. :(

Comment: I did not know `"${!var*}"` syntax to find all the defined variables starting with `var`. Thanks!

Comment: @anishsane : in fact I came to know about it a couple of months ago when skimming through [\[ this \]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) page. This was adopted from ksh IIRC and it first appeared in bash version 2.04 .

Answer (score 0):

Be aware the script you are looking for checks only for the first variable of the function call (i.e. $1). So calling for `function1 $varA $varB $varC` would only check for `varA`

The code below would do the work you expect under the pseudo code you have written:

```
#!/bin/bash

varA="checkAinvariable"
varB="b"
varC="c"
varD="d"
varE="e"
varF="f"

function1 ()
{
        if [[ "$1" != *"A"* ]]; then
                echo "no A in $1"
        elif [[ "$1" == *"A"* ]]; then
                echo "A in $1"
        fi
}

function1 $varA $varB $varC
function1 $varD $varE $varF
```

Output would be:

```
A in checkAinvariable
no A in d
```

Comment: The op said `name of a variable given as argument to a function contains a certain string`. It's name not the value pal !